# Can I disable the TX pin by setting its mode to INPUT while still receiving data on the RX pin of a UART?

Tags: pins, uart, port-mapping

I'm using the ATmega328PB in a personal project with MiniCore. My board streams data in on the RX pin from another microcontroller, but my board also has a DIP switch connected to the TX pin, that's used for configuration. My board has already been manufactured, so a hardware solution means a board redesign and extra cost/time.

This DIP switch is connected between TXD (Arduino pin "1") and GND. Upon startup, I read the value of this pin when in mode INPUT_PULLUP. However, when I go to start the Serial, if this switch is in the closed position, it shorts the TXD pin to GND.

**Is it possible to disable the TX pin by putting it into INPUT mode while still receiving data on the RX pin?**

Comment: modify the library

Answer (score 2):

Well, I ended up answering my own question in a few minutes of forum research.

You can disable the TX pin of the hardware UART with:

```
UCSR0B &= ~bit (TXEN0);
```